OAuth2 Validating tokens on backend when using multiple providers
I'm quite new to using OAuth2 and was wondering how do you validate access tokens that multiple providers?
I have a front end server that is allowing authentication from multiple provides (e.g, Google, Facebook, Micrsoft.....) which is fine but I need to validate where the token was generated from and this is where I am having issues.
My client has the token url when they are signing in
https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
But I need to do the same thing on my backend when they are needing to access it.
jwksUri: Same URL as my client
Auth0 provides a solution but, I don't want to believe they are the only one doing this.
I've considered putting a subtype on a header but I don't think that would be a good idea.
headers: { subtype: 'azure-ad' }
Any insight on this would be appreciated. Thanks!
Placing custom props on submission but I think that would make things insecure. So, want to avoid that as much as possible. Auth0 but they are having issues with the SDK and I do not want to rely on another third-party since I have plenty already and they alone are having problems with their process.

OAUTH STANDARD TOKENS
The recommended pattern from the original RFC 6749 specification is for your clients and APIs to interact with an authorization server (AS) that you host alongside your APIs. This could be Auth0 or some other system.
When required, the AS can federate to identity providers (IDPs) like those you mention. The deeper behaviour is that you should get full control over the scopes and claims issued to access tokens that your APIs receive, so that clients operate with least privilege.
DIRECT IDP INTEGRATIONS
Interacting directly with IDPs adds considerable complexity to both APIs and clients, requiring the use of strategies and workarounds to manage IDP vendor specific behaviour:

APIs might look at the iss claim within JWT access tokens to determine the IDP.
But some access tokens use an opaque format that your APIs cannot read - in some cases the token may only be validatable by the IDP itself.
Token lifetimes, whether you can use refresh tokens, and user session times will all depend on the IDP that the user logs in with.

To summarize, access tokens from IDPs are not designed for your APIs.
ISSUE YOUR OWN ACCESS TOKENS
Ideally you should introduce an AS, but if you need a tactical solution, you might consider doing what an AS does by building a utility token service:

After user logins, the utility API validates the IDP ID token.
The utility API then issues your own set of tokens to clients.
You are in full control of token scopes, claims and lifetimes.
The utility API provides a JWKS URI that APIs can use to validate access tokens.


You can create strategies to handle OAuth.
This
is my repo to log in with google, you can access the auth module to check it out.
the solution I'm doing is FE will call the API from BE to redirect to Oauth page, and the callback will call your BE, your BE will redirect to FE, and return the token and use it
